# In a Multiple Linear Regression Model, is $Cov(\pmb{\hat{y}}, \pmb{e}) = 0$?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, covariance

I'm solving the problem 3.33, from the book "Introduction to Linear Regression Analysis (5th edition)", by Montgomery and I got a doubt.

3.33) Prove that $R^2$ is the square of the correlation between $\pmb{y}$ and $\pmb{\hat{y}}$.

I solved the problem assuming that $Cov(\pmb{\hat{y}}, \pmb{e}) = 0$.

Is this true?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Linear regression decomposes y (vector containing all y-values in the sample) into two components- $\hat{y}$ that is a linear combination of the columns of X (each row of X is an observation of predictor variables), and, $\epsilon$ that can't be described as such a linear combination (because it is orthogonal to the plane formed by the columns of X).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you have any material or a book showing this?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution in "Linear Models in Statistics", from Rencher, Exercise **9.1 d)**:

$Cov[\pmb{e}, \pmb{\hat{y}}] = Cov[(\pmb{I - H})\pmb{y}, \pmb{Hy}] = (\pmb{I - H})(\pmb{\sigma^2I})\pmb{H} = \pmb{\sigma^2}(\pmb{H-H}) = 0$,

where $\pmb{H}$ is the hat matrix.